# Chrome doesn't treat insecure origin as secure despite flag

Tags: google-chrome, getusermedia

I want to test `getUserMedia` on an insecure origin on Chrome on Windows. I am starting Chrome in this way as instructed on goo.gl/rStTGz, a link that shows up in the console if you use insecure origin with `getUserMedia`:

```
start chrome "http://my-ip:8000/index.html" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://my-ip" --user-data-dir=/tmp
```

In `index.html` there is this:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }, stream => console.debug(stream), e => console.error(e))
```

It still gives me error even though I did what the first link said. This error includes another link goo.gl/Y0ZkNV which doesn't mention how to work around this for testing at all.

Is this still supported? It would seem so, because Chrome indeed did start with a fresh profile and shows a warning about using the aforementioned flag. The flag is obviously read by Chrome, but not acted upon. Why?

Comment: did u find any solution ?

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: I have not, no.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the port in the flag as well. Try

```
start chrome "http://my-ip:8000/index.html" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://my-ip:8000" --user-data-dir=/tmp
```

Note that `--user-data-dir` is no longer required. See the note in point #3 [here](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins#TOC-Testing-Powerful-Features).

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't seem to have worked, I still get the `DOMException`. Is there a way to see what CLI switches Chrome was started with from within Chrome so I am able to verify it took it in?

Comment: I've asked [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50057622/2715716) on that. Once I figure out if Chrome sees or ignores the flag, I'll accept your answer.