# How to tell what CLI switches has Chrome been started with?

Tags: google-chrome

I've asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40032182/2715716) previously where I've had a problem with using a CLI switch for influencing Chrome's security model. The question has received a good and helpful answer, but it didn't work for me. I am now unable to determine if the problem is with the answer not being correct or if my installation of Chrome is borked. To try to find out I'd like to start by checking if Chrome sees the CLI arguments I passed to it.

Is there a way to use a running instance of Chrome and check what CLI switches has it been started with? This will help me determine if I've passed the switch in to Chrome correctly and I can move on from there.