# Treat insecure origin as secure

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

The domain **localhost** is treated as a [secure origin by default](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features), which is very handy when testing webapps locally.

It let's you use features like **getUserMedia** without having to use the https protocol.

Because crostini uses the domain **linuxhost** instead of **localhost**, it isn't treated as a secure origin.

There is a chrome flag, **chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure**, that lets you set new domains to be treated as secure, but I've tried all of the following, and everytime, when I restart chrome, the input is empty again.

- linuxhost
- http://linuxhost
- http://linuxhost:3000
- http://linuxhost:3000/

plus all the other combinations of *http://*, *linuxhost*, *:3000*, and */*.

There are some threads about [treating linux.test as secure](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849134) and [changing linuxhost to linux.test](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825010) but those are pretty recent and don't work yet.

Has anyone managed to get that flag to work on chrome os.

I've seen [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032182/chrome-doesnt-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure-despite-flag) that show how to set this flag, but only via the command line, not through the chrome UI.

I'm on the dev channel with crostini working, on version 69.0.3473.0